# Unable to Navigate to any website in Firefox using Playwright

Tags: javascript, firefox, playwright

I created a new Playwright project by following the directions in the playwright site. When I run the test, Playwright is unable to navigate to the intended site in firefox browser.

Playwright version: `1.23.4`

test file contents (in javascript):

```
// @ts-check
const { test, expect } = require('@playwright/test');

test('homepage has Playwright in title and get started link linking to the intro page', async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto('https://playwright.dev/');

  // Expect a title "to contain" a substring.
  await expect(page).toHaveTitle(/Playwright/);

  // create a locator
  const getStarted = page.locator('text=Get started');

  // Expect an attribute "to be strictly equal" to the value.
  await expect(getStarted).toHaveAttribute('href', '/docs/intro');

  // Click the get started link.
  await getStarted.click();
  
  // Expects the URL to contain intro.
  await expect(page).toHaveURL(/.*intro/);
});
```

Configuration file: Default configuration file with no changes
Firefox Version: `102.0.1`
Nightly Browser: `100.0.2`

[Nightly Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Nz98.png)
[HTML Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPhv1.png)

Please let me know if anyone ran into this issue and what is the work around if there is any.

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Can you please click on HTML report. It shows that there is a Timeout while creating a new page:  Timeout of 30000ms exceeded while running fixture "page" setup.
browserContext.newPage: Page closed

    at Object.page [as fn] (C:\Users\****\AutomationFrameworks\playwrightWithFirefox\node_modules\@playwright\test\lib\index.js:718:29)
    at C:\Users\****\AutomationFrameworks\playwrightWithFirefox\node_modules\@playwright\test\lib\fixtures.js:105:81
Pending operations:
  - browserContext.newPage at node_modules\@playwright\test\lib\index.js:718:29

Comment: I have tried this test in my setup and it works without any issues. You can compare with https://github.com/spnraju/demo-playwright-tests. I just created a new test file and added your code. replated require with import. Ran the test with `npm run test -- tests/sample.spec.js --reporter=html` and everything looks good.

Comment: When I run the tests in headed mode, I observed that the code triggers chromium browser 3 times though it mentions in the test result that webkit, firefox, and chromium

Comment: It would be good to look at a sample code from you.

Comment: on further investigation it looks like a certificate issues which I need to work with my company policy. I will update this thread if I am succesful